# Redux: cloning state does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have a very simple question, but…

The code (in a redux/react-native app) of a reducer:

```
...
case SAMPLES_DELETE_REQUEST_SUCCESS: {        
    var newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    const indexToDelete = newState.samples.findIndex( sample => {
      return sample.id == action.sample.id
    })
    newState.samples.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
    debugger;
    return newState
  }
...
```

Ok, I copy the state and store it into newState. But when I do `newState.samples.splice(indexToDelete, 1)`, `newState` is correctly modified, but also `state`! Why?? I must be tired…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function modifies original array. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does not do deep cloning. Therefore you are still modifying the original state!

You will have to manually copy the nested object(or array) you want to clone:

```
// Deep Clone
obj1 = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
let obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Answer (score 2):

As someone mention before you could use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) to create a new copy of the entire object (nested object as well). If you don't want to do that, you could check libraries like [Inmutable JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)


Also if you want to use spread notation, a better way to do that will be:

```
return {
  ...state,
  samples: state.samples.filter(sample => sample.id !== action.sample.id)
}
```